What is the punishment for unintentional sins?
I have indirectly blasphemed the vedas by saying I am Muslim(as manu smriti holds all darshanas apart from Vedas are false)..I heard that there is no atonement for blaspheming the vedas..but is it atonable if committed unintentionally..what is atonement for unintentional sin? Kindly answer in the light of scriptures

I am going ahead and vote to close this question, it does not enlighten anyone and the intention is purely personal advice. Atonement? say 1008 times "Krishna" and I am sure you will be fine. also "watch and pray", basically watch yourself - don't let material nature force you to do things.  take shelter in the Lord with all your attachment, fear and anger. Bg 4.10, BG 4.10: Being free from attachment, fear, and anger, becoming fully absorbed in Me, and taking refuge in Me, many persons in the past became purified by knowledge of Me, and thus attained My divine love.

I don't think there is any concept of blasphemy in Hinduism.Manusmriti dictates such in a more serious context. It talks about actual comparison between Vedas and other darshanas. Not against some witty jokes

There is I had read a puran where blasphemy and slander were criticised but I don't remember where I read
